# Jquery Ajax Request show what record is being processed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I please will want to know if anyone know how to go about showing which record is being processed in a jquery ajax request. For instance:
I have a html input from index.html, jquery_ajax.js, session_dispaly.php and  search.php.

And an on keyup event that listen for enter pressed
I also have a jquery ajax that sends a post request and a php page that process that request...

Now what i want to do is... while the php page process the request i want to keep the user informed on what is goin on.. Say:

My php search.php is looping through 1-1000

While its looping i want to tell the user via session_display.php that,

1 is being processed

2 is being processed

And so on

Thank you.

```
index.html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing Message Display</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href="depends/styles/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href="depends/styles/styles.css">
        <script src="depends/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="depends/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="form-action">
                <input class="form-control span6" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Please enter user name">
            </div>
    </body>
    <script src="depends/js/jquery_ajax.js"></script>
</html>

jquery_ajax.js
    $('#search').on( 'keyup', function(e) {
        if (  e.which === 13 ){
            $.ajax({
                url: "depends/php_request/search.php",
                method:"POST",
                data: {params:$('#search').val()},
                always: function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "depends/display_session.php",
                        success:function(responseStatus){
                            console.log(responseStatus)
                        }
                    })
                },
                success:function(successResponse){
                    console.log(successResponse)
                }
            })
        }
    })

display_session.php
<?php
@session_start();
echo $_SESSION['Names'];
unset($_SESSION['Names']);
?>
```

And

```
search.php
<?php
@session_start();
$name=array();
for($i = 1; $i <=100000; $i++){
    $_SESSION['Names'] = $i . 'is being processed';
    $name[] = $i;    
}
echo json_encode($name);
?>
```

Comment: Can you post code of what you have tried.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Comment: Plz find desc above!

Answer (score 0):

You can either use console.log()

```
`$.ajax({
    //params goes here
    always: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});`
```

before you `.keyup();` on input, open your developer tools pressing `F12` on Chrome/Firefox to see the data returned from your code.
Remember to specify yout dataType to HTML to see errors or json to see arrays.
Or you can use an HTML element like a `div#test` and place your return on it to see the results

```
`$.ajax({
    //params goes here
    always: function(data) {
        $("div#test").html(data);
    }`
});`
```

Remember to set your `dataType` properly
I think it is well explained.

Comment: sorry i was typing from my mobile device previously.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
console.log(data);
```

OR

```
alert(data);
```

OR

```
$("div#test").html(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, you can do the following:

```
$.ajax({
    // ajax params
    beforeSend: function() {
        alert('tell user that request is under process');
        // or you can open a modal box
    },
    done: function() {
        alert('tell user that request is done');
        // or you can close modal box
    }
});
```

You can show a progress bar, there is a lot of tutorials of how to do it. Just Google it.